# CXJS Component as Child to a native react component

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, cxjs

I mixed a lot of functional components in cxjs with plain react components.

but sometimes when i try to use a cxjs-component as a child of a react component, i get a

```
"
error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
"
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you so much !

```
Code which causes this problem:

CXJS component example, which works within cxjs as a child but causes error in react as a child:
import { Chart, Gridlines, NumericAxis } from 'cx/charts';
import { Rectangle, Svg } from 'cx/svg';
import {Controller} from "cx/ui";

export  class Dcc extends Controller {
 onInit(){
     alert("Demochart initialised");
 }
}

    export default <cx>
    <div class="widgets" controller = {Dcc}>
        tiomo test
        <Svg style="width:300px;height:200px" margin="10 20 30 50">
            <Chart axes={{
                x: <NumericAxis />,
                y: <NumericAxis vertical/>
            }}>
                <Rectangle fill="white" />
                <Gridlines />
            </Chart>
        </Svg>
        timo
    </div>
</cx>
```

and now a react grid component to use it with: - i can add react children as much as i like. but no cxjs like the above.

```
import React from 'react';
import { VDOM } from "cx-react";
import { findDOMNode } from "react-dom";
import GridLayout from 'react-grid-layout';
import "./index.scss";



import Demochart from "../../demochart";

export default class MyGrid extends React.Component {


    render() {



        return (


            <GridLayout className="layout" cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>

                <div key="g" data-grid={{x: 14, y: 5, w: 6, h: 6}}><Demochart/></div>


            </GridLayout>

        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you include the code that is giving you this error in the question? You most likely have an incorrect import statement, or you are using one of your own components with a lowercased first letter, e.g. `myComponent` instead of `MyComponent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cx` wrapper is required in order to use CxJS widgets inside React components.

```
<MyReactComponent>
  <Cx store={myCxStore} subscribe>
     <Grid ... />
  </Cx>
</MyReactComponent>
```

CxJS components cannot work without a store, so you must pass one.

It's more common to use React components inside CxJS.

```
<cx>
  <div>
    <MyReactComponent />
  </div>
</cx>
```

Comment: Thank you, Marco. From where do i have to import Cx then within the react component?

Comment: You can import it like this: `import {Cx} from "cx/ui";`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved !